# TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use `.get()` to construct a NumPy array explicitly

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I'm trying to pad an array with another one in cupy.
Below is a MWE:

```
import cupy as cp
a = cp.random.rand(294, 302, 372)
b = cp.asarray([[5, 5], [5, 5], [2, 2]])
cp.pad(a, b, 'symmetric')
```

Unfortunately, this yields:

> TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use ".get()" to construct a NumPy array explicitly.

Both a and b are on `CUDA Device 0`, so I do not see the problem.
I also do not understand why I would need ".get()" here, as no conversion from cupy to numpy is required. Please note that .get does not solve my problem as in the related post.

Comment: `pad` doesn't allow a cupy array as its second argument (`pad_width`). See https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.pad.html#cupy.pad

Comment: Thanks, I saw it now. I need to specify the pad_width as a numpy array.